# setup low Latency web server from two location

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver

how to setup two web server one from Asia and one from USA so that whenever request comes in it's should go to nearest server?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing building your own CDN and it's not a simple task that can be answered in one paragraph. This document describes one way to do it using bind and GeoIP (and some other tools.) http://blog.unixy.net/2010/07/how-to-build-your-own-cdn-using-bind-geoip-nginx-and-varnish/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the client's **geographical location** based on its **IP** ([this tool](http://www.iplocation.net/) could help), then use a tool like [this](http://www.geobytes.com/citydistancetool/) to determine the distances from its location to yours (Asia and USA) and finally redirect the client to the nearest one.

The last step is backend-dependent, i.e Apache, Nginx, Node.js, etc.

I think Apache has some mods (**mod_geoip**, **mod_geoip2**).
And here are some Node.js modules (**geoipcity**, **node-geoip**).

I hope it helps you.

> Sorry but I cannot publish more than 2 links because of my reputation :/

Answer (score 0):

If you had the IP of the geographical location using the tool stated by Sam, you could use an Amazon EC2 and there cloud services to host a web instance with static IP endpoints tied to your servers. Then you could test whatever you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Amazon EC2 Instances are Free for the first year of usage, but they do charge based on your usage of the server!